# how to get content after sitename of current page url using php

Tags: php

I want the details after sitename from current URL.

For eg: if current url is `http://mysite.com/a/article`, I want to get the content after `http://mysite.com/`, in this case `a/article`. Is there any PHP function to get these details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // will print /a/article
```

If you don't need the '/':

```
echo substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1); // will print a/article
```